# SQL query to find partial string match across 2 tables

Tags: sql, csv, join, mariadb, inner-join

I'm trying to find any items in column address (users table) that have a match in Address (address_effect table). I'm testing this on my local system with XAMPP (using MariaDB)

### user table

```
+------------------+-----------------+------------------+--------------------------+
|        ID        |    firstname    |  lastname        |    address               |
|                  |                 |                  |                          |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|     1            |    john         |    doe           |james street, idaho, usa  |                    
|                  |                 |                  |                          |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|     2            |    cindy        |   smith          |rollingwood av,lyn, canada|
|                  |                 |                  |                          |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|     3            |    rita         |   chatsworth     |arajo ct, fremont, cali   |
|                  |                 |                  |                          |
+------------------+-----------------+---------------------+-----------------------+
|     4            |    randy        |   plies          |smith spring, lima, peru  |                       
|                  |                 |                  |                          |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|     5            |    Matt         |   gwalio         |park lane, atlanta, usa   |
|                  |                 |                  |                          |
+------------------+-----------------+------------------+--------------------------+
```

### address_effect table

```
+---------+----------------+
|idaho    |potato, tater   |
+--------------------------+
|canada   |cold, tundra    |
+--------------------------+
|fremont  | crowded        |
+--------------------------+
|peru     |alpaca          |
+--------------------------+
|atlanta  |peach, cnn      |
+--------------------------+
|usa      |big, hard       |
+--------+-----------------+
```

I've tried using inner join with LIKE to find matching string.

If I use this query it doesn't find any items:

```
SELECT users.firstname, users.lastname, users.address
FROM users
INNER JOIN db_name.address_effect
ON
(address_effect.Address LIKE '%' + users.address + '%'
OR users.address LIKE '%' || address_effect.Address || '%')
```

Then I tried the following query, it lists all the items from user table, instead of only those items that have a match in address_effect

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.firstname, users.lastname, users.address
FROM users
INNER JOIN db_name.address_effect
ON
(address_effect.Address LIKE '%' || users.address || '%'
OR users.address LIKE '%' || address_effect.Address || '%')
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: In your sample data, everything has a match.

Comment: You're right! I mistakenly added last few records in the address_effect table that shouldn't have been there.
@GMB query with find_in_set seems to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand your sample data, you want to match parts of `users` addresses against values in the other table.

You might want to try `find_in_set()`. It is more accurate that a `LIKE` match, since it matches on individual elements only:

```
SELECT u.firstname, u.lastname, u.address user_address, a.*
FROM users u
INNER JOIN address_effect a 
    ON FIND_IN_SET(a.address, REPLACE(u.address, ', ', ','))
```

This matches if `address_effect(address)` can be found in the CSV list stored in `users(address)`.

Comment: It worked. 
I didn't know about find_in_set and it sure is handy and query runs much faster than with Like. 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Fyi, I asked an additional question to this query [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62964855/updating-table-based-on-the-results-of-previous-table)