# Updating table based on the results of previous query

Tags: sql, mariadb, inner-join

**How can I update the table based on the results of the previous query?**

The [original query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62579803/sql-query-to-find-partial-string-match-across-2-tables) (big thanks to [GMB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10676716/gmb)) can find any items in address (users table) that have a match in address (address_effect table).

From the result of this query, I want to find the count of address in the address_effect table and add it into a new column in the table “users”.  For example, john doe has a match with idaho and usa in the address column so it’ll show a count of ‘2’ in the count column.

Fyi, I'm testing this on my local system with XAMPP (using MariaDB).

### user table

```
+--------+-------------+---------------+--------------------------+--------+
|    ID  |  firstname  |  lastname     |    address               |  count |
|        |             |               |                          |        |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|     1  |    john     |    doe        |james street, idaho, usa  |        |                    
|        |             |               |                          |        |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|     2  |    cindy    |   smith       |rollingwood av,lyn, canada|        |
|        |             |               |                          |        |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|     3  |    rita     |   chatsworth  |arajo ct, alameda, cali   |        |
|        |             |               |                          |        |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|     4  |    randy    |   plies       |smith spring, lima, peru  |        |                       
|        |             |               |                          |        |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|     5  |    Matt     |   gwalio      |park lane, atlanta, usa   |        |
|        |             |               |                          |        |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

### address_effect table

```
+---------+----------------+
|address   |effect         |
+---------+----------------+
|idaho    |potato, tater   |
+--------------------------+
|canada   |cold, tundra    |
+--------------------------+
|fremont  | crowded        |
+--------------------------+
|peru     |alpaca          |
+--------------------------+
|atlanta  |peach, cnn      |
+--------------------------+
|usa      |big, hard       |
+--------+-----------------+
```

Comment: You should fix your data model and stop storing CSV data in your SQL tables.

Comment: What data format should I choose then? The original data file is in csv format.

Comment: Normalize your data.  Google "SQL normalized data"

Comment: @IshuVerma . . . Do not store multiple values within a column.  You need multiple tables, and one of those tables would have a column with each address/effect combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a correlated subquery which returns the number of matches:

```
UPDATE user u
SET u.count = (
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM address_effect a
  WHERE FIND_IN_SET(a.address, REPLACE(u.address, ', ', ','))
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=7c3d57d97ba0ab35268ff99065366e65).
Results:

```
> ID | firstname | lastname   | address                    | count
> -: | :-------- | :--------- | :------------------------- | ----:
>  1 | john      | doe        | james street, idaho, usa   |     2
>  2 | cindy     | smith      | rollingwood av,lyn, canada |     1
>  3 | rita      | chatsworth | arajo ct, alameda, cali    |     0
>  4 | randy     | plies      | smith spring, lima, peru   |     1
>  5 | Matt      | gwalio     | park lane, atlanta, usa    |     2
```

Answer (score 1):

Notice: I checked it in MySQL, but not in MariaDB.

The count column of users table may be able to be updated using UPDATE statement with INNER JOIN. Then you can use a query that modifies the original query to use "GROUP BY".

```
UPDATE users AS u
INNER JOIN
(
  -- your original query modified
  SELECT u.ID AS ID, count(u.ID) AS count
  FROM users u
  INNER JOIN address_effect a 
      ON FIND_IN_SET(a.address, REPLACE(u.address, ', ', ','))
  GROUP BY u.ID
) AS c ON u.ID=c.ID
SET u.count=c.count;
```

Comment: nice one, i could easily manipulate it in select too.

Comment: It can also be used to update multiple columns. And I feel that it's simple.