# Update Records in Table based on query result and variable - result only returns record for first int in variable

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-8.0

I want to update records in table Users that are not present in table UserActions (see [sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3563eef/8) or [sql and data at gist.github](https://gist.github.com/surfmuggle/7d23b543739cd4f4af8674238e363979))

My tables

```
Table Users
ID  | UserName     | isActive
 1  | Ben Busy     |    1            
 2  | Lui Lazy     |    1         <-- never logged in
 3  | Emmy Eager   |    1
 4  | Lana Later   |    1         <-- never logged in

Table UserActions
ID  | User_ID  |  Type   |   ActionDate
 1  |    1     |  Login  |   2021-01-01      <-- Joe
 2  |    3     |  Login  |   2021-01-02      <-- Eda
 3  |    1     |  Login  |   2021-01-02      <-- Joe
 4  |    1     |  Login  |   2021-01-03      <-- Joe
```

I want to set isActive = 0 for all Users that never logged in.

This query returns the userIDs that never logged in:

```
SELECT ID FROM Users u LEFT JOIN UserActions ua
          ON u.ID = ua.User_ID
          AND (ua.Type = "Login" OR ua.Type = NULL)
WHERE ua.ActionDate IS NULL
```

I was not able to use [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11588710) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62964855/) so i thought that [using a varible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10070406/) `SET @userIDs := (....)` should work as well

```
SET @userIDs := (
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(ID SEPARATOR ', ') FROM Users u LEFT JOIN UserActions ua
          ON u.ID = ua.User_ID
          AND (ua.Type = "Login" OR ua.Type = NULL)
WHERE ua.ActionDate IS NULL);
```

The varible `@userIDs` contains all the relevant user-ids that never logged in `(2,4)`.

But this statement

```
SELECT * FROM Users where ID in (@userIDs);
```

only returns the first result.

#### Questions

- Why does `where ID in @myVar` not work?
- Is there a way besides using a [temporary table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524858/)?

#### Code and Data

- [sql and data at gist](https://gist.github.com/surfmuggle/7d23b543739cd4f4af8674238e363979)
- [sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3563eef/8)

Comment: This is my  attempt to avoid a temp table `UPDATE Users INNER JOIN (SELECT u.ID FROM Users u LEFT JOIN UserActions ua
              ON u.ID = ua.User_ID
              AND (ua.Type = "Login" OR ua.Type = NULL)
              WHERE ua.ActionDate IS NULL) as subquery
    ON u.ID = subquery.ID
 set u.ID = 0; ` but it was not running on fiddle (time out)

Comment: Note that nothing is equal to null, not even null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can just use [NOT EXISTS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html):

```
UPDATE Users u 
SET u.IsActive=0
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT user_id FROM UserActions ua
       WHERE (ua.Type = "Login" OR ua.Type = NULL) AND u.ID=ua.user_id);
```

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a01fb946364ee05620f159db8cfcbcf7)

### Update 3rd party edit

If you want to use a variable you can do it with [find_in_set](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c8427b90564a59e662d32c54dcc0c2e7)

```
SET @userIDs := (
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(u.ID SEPARATOR ',') FROM Users u 
             LEFT JOIN UserActions ua
              ON u.ID = ua.User_ID
              AND (ua.Type = "Login" OR ua.Type = NULL)
    WHERE ua.ActionDate IS NULL);
```

And then

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE FIND_IN_SET(Users.ID, @userIDs);
```

See this [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c8427b90564a59e662d32c54dcc0c2e7)

Comment: Do you know why  `ID in @myVar` not work?

Comment: Oh yes.. I remember encounter something similar before but I couldn't find any official MySQL documentation regarding on it. However, I was satisfied with the explanation from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21101272/10910692). Hope it can help