# SQL query to find a partial string match that could include special characters

Tags: sql, mariadb

**SQL query with special character ()**

The [original query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62579803/sql-query-to-find-partial-string-match-across-2-tables) (big thanks to [GMB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10676716/gmb)) can find any items in address (users table) that have a match in address (address_effect table).

The query works fine if address contains ',' but I can't seem to make it work if there is '()' in the address field.

Here is the sql query that's not working:

```
UPDATE users u 
SET u.COUNT = (
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM address_effect a 
  WHERE FIND_IN_SET(a.address, REPLACE(u.address, ', ', ','')')) 
)
```

Fyi, I'm testing this on my local system with XAMPP (using MariaDB).

I tried to identify '()' as an escape character by prepending it with backslash '' but it doesn't help.

### user table

```
+--------+-------------+---------------+--------------------------+--------+
|    ID  |  firstname  |  lastname     |    address               |  count |
|        |             |               |                          |        |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|     1  |    john     |    doe        |james street, idaho, usa  |        |                    
|        |             |               |                          |        |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|     2  |    cindy    |   smith       |rollingwood av,lyn, canada|        |
|        |             |               |                          |        |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|     3  |    rita     |   chatsworth  |arajo ct, alameda, cali   |        |
|        |             |               |                          |        |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|     4  |    randy    |   plies       |smith spring, lima, (peru)|        |                       
|        |             |               |                          |        |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|     5  |    Matt     |   gwalio      |park lane, (atlanta), usa |        |
|        |             |               |                          |        |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

### address_effect table

```
+---------+----------------+
|address   |effect         |
+---------+----------------+
|idaho    |potato, tater   |
+--------------------------+
|canada   |cold, tundra    |
+--------------------------+
|fremont  | crowded        |
+--------------------------+
|peru     |alpaca          |
+--------------------------+
|atlanta  |peach, cnn      |
+--------------------------+
|usa      |big, hard       |
+--------+-----------------+
```

Comment: If you design your tables correctly you won't have these kinds of problems. Storing a comma-separated list of values in a column is almost always a sign of a poor database design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using regular expressions for this.  It seems more general than fiddling with the string:

```
update users u
    set count = (select count(*)
                 from address_effect ae
                 where u.address regexp concat('[[:<:]]', ae.address, '[[:>:]]'))
                );
```

The funky character class is MySQL's way of delineating a word boundary (I am more used to `\W` but MySQL doesn't support that).

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=82e4b4c4dc09ebafd6c7a840ba4ee5fe) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: I can see the query working in db<>fiddle but don't understand the logic.
- What's the purpose of assigning valued to count in the first query.
- How does this expression work: 
where u.address regexp concat('([^a-zA-Z]|^)', ae.address, '([^a-zA-Z]|$)')
       )

Comment: @IshuVerma . . . That checks if there is a match between the words of the address in `users` and the names in `address_effect`.

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff. What's the purpose of assigning values to count column in the first query.

Comment: @IshuVerma . . . That allows you to validate the results before running the `update`.

Answer (score 1):

Just like you replace the space after each comma with just a comma, use `REPLACE()` to remove the chars `'('` and `')'`:

```
FIND_IN_SET(a.address, REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(u.address, ', ', ','), '(', ''), ')', ''))
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7FoqQ9iL8cMNQN8PyjLqs/0).
Results:

```
| ID  | firstname | lastname   | address                    | count |
| --- | --------- | ---------- | -------------------------- | ----- |
| 1   | john      | doe        | james street, idaho, usa   | 2     |
| 2   | cindy     | smith      | rollingwood av,lyn, canada | 1     |
| 3   | rita      | chatsworth | arajo ct, alameda, cali    | 0     |
| 4   | randy     | plies      | smith spring, lima, (peru) | 1     |
| 5   | Matt      | gwalio     | park lane, (atlanta), usa  | 2     |
```

Comment: This query works but I realize that if the data is not clean i.e. if there is a missing comma or another character is used as separator then this approach won't work. I liked @GordonLinoff query better as it will find any match for the string irrespective of separator.

Comment: This code works for the requirement as you posted it.

Comment: Yes, definitely meets the requirements that I posted. Thanks.